Namespace not define
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_native_timezone'.

Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.


Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about

setting the namespace.
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           12.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\KimoStore\celender>

History restored`

This error appear when I try to build my flutter app . The app run normally in default flutter app put I notice that maybe the error appear with me when I try to build local Database in android phone I try apdate flutter to lastest version and upgrade AGP assistant and the Namespace error is appear
